# Pandas measure elapsed time when condition is true

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following dataframe:

```
                 dt binary
2016-01-01 00:00:00  False
2016-01-01 00:00:01  False
2016-01-01 00:00:02  False
2016-01-01 00:00:03  False
2016-01-01 00:00:04   True
2016-01-01 00:00:05   True
2016-01-01 00:00:06   True
2016-01-01 00:00:07  False
2016-01-01 00:00:08  False
2016-01-01 00:00:09   True
2016-01-01 00:00:10   True
```

I would like to sum the elapsed time when `binary` is `True`. I'm sharing my solution, which implements it, but something tells me there should be an easier way since it is a pretty basic feature of time series data. Note that the data is most probably equidistant, but I can't rely on that.

```
df['binary_grp'] = (df.binary.diff(1) != False).astype(int).cumsum()
# Throw away False values
df = df[df.binary]
groupby = df.groupby('binary_grp')
df = pd.DataFrame({'timespan': groupby.dt.last() - groupby.dt.first()})
return df.timespan.sum().seconds / 60.0
```

The trickiest part is probably the first line. What it does, it basically assigns an incremented number to each consecutive block. Here's how the data looks like after that:

```
                 dt binary  binary_grp
2016-01-01 00:00:00  False           1
2016-01-01 00:00:01  False           1
2016-01-01 00:00:02  False           1
2016-01-01 00:00:03  False           1
2016-01-01 00:00:04   True           2
2016-01-01 00:00:05   True           2
2016-01-01 00:00:06   True           2
2016-01-01 00:00:07  False           3
2016-01-01 00:00:08  False           3
2016-01-01 00:00:09   True           4
2016-01-01 00:00:10   True           4
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I guess this code is performant, my worry is readability.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your solution is nice.

Another solution:

Compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), get groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

After filtering is possible use `apply` with difference by selecting with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
df['binary_grp'] = (df.binary.ne(df.binary.shift())).cumsum()

df = df[df.binary]

s = df.groupby('binary_grp')['dt'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
print (s)
binary_grp
2   00:00:02
4   00:00:01
Name: dt, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

all_time =  s.sum().seconds / 60.0
print (all_time)
0.05
```

---

In your solution new `DataFrame` is not necessary if need only `all_time`:

```
groupby = df.groupby('binary_grp')

s = groupby.dt.last() - groupby.dt.first()
all_time =  s.sum().seconds / 60.0
print (all_time)
0.05
```

But if need it is possible create it from `Series` `s` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = s.to_frame('timestamp')
print (df1)
           timestamp
binary_grp          
2           00:00:02
4           00:00:01
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

You want to find the sum of time spanned across the entire series where `binary` is `True`.

However, we have to make some choices or assumptions

```
                    dt  binary
0  2016-01-01 00:00:00   False
1  2016-01-01 00:00:01   False
2  2016-01-01 00:00:02   False
3  2016-01-01 00:00:03   False
4  2016-01-01 00:00:04    True # <- This where time starts
5  2016-01-01 00:00:05    True
6  2016-01-01 00:00:06    True
7  2016-01-01 00:00:07   False # <- And ends here. So this would
8  2016-01-01 00:00:08   False # be 00:00:07 - 00:00:04 or 3 seconds
9  2016-01-01 00:00:09    True # <- Starts again
10 2016-01-01 00:00:10    True # <- But ends here because
                               # I don't have another Timestamp
```

With those assumptions, we can use `diff`, multiply, and `sum`

```
df.dt.diff().shift(-1).mul(df.binary).sum()

Timedelta('0 days 00:00:04')
```

---

We can then use this concept along with `groupby`

```
# Use xor and cumsum to identify change in True to False and False to True
grps = (df.binary ^ df.binary.shift()).cumsum()
mask = df.binary.groupby(grps).first()
df.dt.diff().shift(-1).groupby(grps).sum()[mask]

binary
1   00:00:03
3   00:00:01
Name: dt, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or without the mask

```
pd.concat([df.dt.diff().shift(-1).groupby(grps).sum(), mask], axis=1)

             dt  binary
binary                 
0      00:00:04   False
1      00:00:03    True
2      00:00:02   False
3      00:00:01    True
```